# Java: Alternative to BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm having issues with `BufferedWriter`/`BufferedReader`.

Basically, whenever I try to read a file with `BufferedReader.readLine()` it reads everything up to the new line character (i.e. The new line character is omitted).

For instance:

```
String temp;
File f = new File(path.toURI());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //Work with temp
}
```

I know about the existence of `BufferedReader#newLine()`, but it appears that it does not exactly get the newline (delimiter?) that was previously omitted.

From my understanding if I were to readline the following:

```
abcd\n
efgh\r\n
ijkl\r
```

It will return:

```
abcd\n
efgh\n
ijkl\n
```

What I am asking is, is there any class that is able to read characters without omitting them like `BufferedInputStream`, while retaining the ability to read line like `BufferedReader#readLine()`

Comment: you are reading a line, it uses "new line" as `delimitor`

Comment: @nafas delimit**e**r

Comment: @meskobalazs yeah that. :D

Comment: From the javadoc `readline(): Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.`. So you want to behave readline() to consider only the line feed character as end of the line and preserve the carriage return character?

Comment: There is no such method as `BufferedReader.newLine()`. If you don't want what `readLine()` does, don't use it. There are three other `read()` methods available that don't trim line terminators. You don't need an alternative for that.

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a `linux/unix` line ending while `\r\n` is `windows` line ending.

if there is such a file that has both line ending it should be reformatted.

My suggestion would be if you ever come across such file, just reformat it to either use `\n` or `\r\n` (depending on your OS not that it matter nowadays). it makes your life easier so the life of the next person that is going to use it next.

Alternatively (please don't use this :/)  you can override `BufferReader.readLine(Boolean b)` to this:

```
String readLine(boolean ignoreLF) throws IOException {
     StringBuffer s = null;
     int startChar;

     synchronized (lock) {
         ensureOpen();
         boolean omitLF = ignoreLF || skipLF;

     bufferLoop:
         for (;;) {

             if (nextChar >= nChars)
                 fill();
             if (nextChar >= nChars) { /* EOF */
                 if (s != null && s.length() > 0){
                   if(skipLF=='\r'){
                     return s.toString() + "\r\n";
                   }else{
                     return s.toString() + "\n";
                   }
                 }
                 else
                     return null;
             }
             boolean eol = false;
             char c = 0;
             int i;

             /* Skip a leftover '\n', if necessary */
             if (omitLF && (cb[nextChar] == '\n'))
                 nextChar++;
             skipLF = false;
             omitLF = false;

         charLoop:
             for (i = nextChar; i < nChars; i++) {
                 c = cb[i];
                 if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r')) {
                     eol = true;
                     break charLoop;
                 }
             }

             startChar = nextChar;
             nextChar = i;

             if (eol) {
                 String str;
                 if (s == null) {
                     str = new String(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                 } else {
                     s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
                     str = s.toString();
                 }
                 nextChar++;
                 if (c == '\r') {
                     skipLF = true;
                 }
                 if(skipLF=='\r'){
                   return str + "\r\n";
                 }else{
                   return str + "\n";
                 }
             }

             if (s == null)
                 s = new StringBuffer(defaultExpectedLineLength);
             s.append(cb, startChar, i - startChar);
         }
     }
 }
```

SOURCE CODE edited from:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.readLine%28boolean%29

Comment: Don't use code formatting to for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't be too much trouble to extend [`BufferedReader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.readLine%28boolean%29) to include a `\n` or `\r` in the return from `readLine()`. In fact, the package-protected `readLine(boolean ignoreLF)` function is all you'd need to override:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r') delimiter in the result, or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.
>
> **Parameters**: `ignoreLF` If true, the
>   next '\n' will be skipped
>
> **Returns**: `A String` containing the contents of
>   the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if
>   the end of the stream has been reached
>
> **Throws**: `IOException` If an I/O
>   error occurs
>
> See also: `LineNumberReader.readLine()`

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to extend from `BufferedReader` and override the `readLine()` method (as it was already proposed in other answers).

Take this simplified example only as a PoC.

```
class MyReader extends BufferedReader {
    int size = 8192;

    public MyReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public MyReader(Reader in, int sz) {
        super(in, sz);
        this.size = sz;
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.size);
        for (int read = super.read(); read >= 0 && read != '\n'; read = super.read()) {
            sb.append((char) read);
        }
        // in case you want also to preserve the line feed character
        // sb.append('\n');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

.

```
public class MyReaderDemo{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String text = "abcd\n"
                + "efgh\r\n"
                + "ijkl\r";

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
        );

        // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));
        BufferedReader in = new MyReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in.readLine().getBytes()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in.readLine().getBytes()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in.readLine().getBytes()));

    }
}
```

**output with BufferedReader**

```
[97, 98, 99, 100]
[101, 102, 103, 104]
[105, 106, 107, 108]
```

**output with MyReader**

```
[97, 98, 99, 100]
[101, 102, 103, 104, 13]
[105, 106, 107, 108, 13]
```